# Azure Managed instance Could not find stored procedure 'sys.sp_MS_marksystemobject'

Tags: database, azure, sys

I am a sysadmin on the server (Azure Managed Instance), I am trying to create system procedures in master database and mark them as system using [sys].[sp_MS_marksystemobject] procedure in n Azure Managed instance but I get object not found on sp_MS_marksystemobject.

USE master
GO
EXEC [sys].[sp_MS_marksystemobject] [sp_help_revlogin] ;

is failing with

Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 3
Could not find stored procedure 'sys.sp_MS_marksystemobject'.

SELECT name, SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) From sys.all_objects WHERE name = 'sp_MS_marksystemobject'
is returning the objectname and sys as schema

SELECT OBJECT_ID('[sys].[sp_MS_marksystemobject]')
returns null

How can I create my own sp_* named system procedures in master database and mark them as system?
THank you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "USE Master"

Connect to the Master database using SQL Server management studio.

Comment: No difference, same result.